# Gunicorn timeout during file download

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn

I'm using **nginx** as reverse-proxy to be able to access my Django API and also serve static files. 
My Django API is using **gunicorn**.

I have an endpoint allowing a user to download a csv file. I followed the instructions here, Streaming large CSV files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-csv/

Here is the nginx configuration:

```
upstream docker-api {
    server api;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxxx.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to//privkey.pem;
    include /path/to/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /path/to/ssl-dhparams.pem;


    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }

    location /uploads {
        autoindex on;
        alias /uploads/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://docker-api;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

This is the command I use to launch my **gunicorn** server:

```
gunicorn my_api.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:80 --enable-stdio-inheritance -w 2 -t 180 -k gevent
```

And when I try to download the file, Gunicorn always timeout my request after 3 minutes. It should not timeout a streaming http response.

Answer (score 3):

this error is typically raised by two things:

1. Nginx timeout: in which you should add these two lines of code to
   the Nginx file:

   - first, go to the file you created in the following directory (in my case named `myproject`)

> $ nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

- the `location /` part of your file should look like this:(notice the
  timeout parts):

```html
location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    }
```

- then restart Nginx:

> $ systemctl start nginx

2. gunicorn timeout: go to the exact directory:

> $ nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

- add the `--timeout 300` to the file, under `[service]` section. for more help you see the whole file bellow from [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04):

```html
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --timeout 300 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- next, restart gunicorn:

> $ systemctl daemon-reload
>
> $ systemctl restart gunicorn.socket gunicorn.service

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your gunicorn command.

Let's take a look:

> gunicorn my_api.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:80 --enable-stdio-inheritance -w 2 -t 180 -k gevent

`-t`  on your gunicorn command stands for `timeout`, it's in seconds, and your gunicorn worker timeouts because you've set the timeout to 180 seconds (3 minutes).

> And when I try to download the file, Gunicorn always timeout my request after 3 minutes.

To solve this issue, you can simply increase the timeout, for example, the following gunicorn command will set the timeout to 5 minutes:

> gunicorn my_api.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:80 --enable-stdio-inheritance -w 2 -t 300 -k gevent

Check the documentation for more information: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout

Comment: But what if the file take more than 5 minutes? Is there a way to avoid the timeout during a streaming http connection? I understand that Gunicorn timeout every other requests after 3 minutes but it should not timeout a streaming request

Comment: Then you have to set up a separate gunicorn instance running the same application or a separate application serving files with a different timeout. As a side note if you are serving files from a hard drive then there may be no reason to use Django, maybe you can serve with nginx directly?

Comment: There is no way to say that if the request is a Streaming Http request then the timeout doesn't apply to it?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no way to do that. I also had issue with Gunicorn timeouts, because i had Flask route that took too long to return, i ended up using Redis Queue ([python-rq](https://python-rq.org/)) instead.